# Is it possible to use tmpfs on a GitHub Workflow Service?

Tags: docker, performance, continuous-integration, github-actions

When I run automated tests locally, I make the database use tmpfs volume, to leverage RAM speed. Given I'll destroy all data at the end of the execution, there is no concern for durability anyway.

I have a GitHub Workflow that provisions a database as a service container. The workflow runs automated tests that connects to that database and performs various operations, which are part of the tests.

Is it possible to do mount volumes on tmpfs on Github Workflow? Is there a way to specify that the container service should mount a certain directory as tmpfs?

Does GitHub already mounts everything on tmpfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does GitHub already mounts everything on tmpfs

No, when a workflow runs on GitHub Actions, it runs on a VM whose storage is mapped to an SSD. ([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources)). Your default workspace (`/mnt/`), for example, is backed by disk, not memory. Ephemeral space used by containers is also backed by disk (in `/var/lib/docker/` on the host).

There are, however, tmpfs memory-backed directories mounted by default on the runner host.

For actions running on ubuntu, you can run `df -h` to see which directories are on the tmpfs filesystem:

```bash
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        84G   55G   29G  66% /
tmpfs           3.4G  176K  3.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.4G  1.1M  1.4G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1        14G  4.1G  9.0G  31% /mnt
tmpfs           695M   12K  695M   1% /run/user/1001
```

> to leverage RAM speed

If your goal is just to make sure you are using RAM-backed storage, put your data under `/dev/shm/` which is backed by tmpfs memory storage and is available by default. Of course, you want to make sure your data (and anything else that might need /dev/shm) is small enough to fit.

For *job containers*, you can control the `shm_size` through the `container:options:` key. For services, there doesn't seem to be such an option. I would guess the default shm size applies.

> Is there a way to specify that the container service should mount a certain directory as tmpfs?

If the default `/dev/shm/` doesn't work for your needs, you should be able to just [specify a volume mount](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idvolumes) from a source directory that is backed by tmpfs on the host.

e.g., with `jobs.<job_id>.services.<service_id>.volumes`:

```yaml
volumes:
  - /dev/shm/sourcedata:/path/to/dbdata
```